# Проблема с кодировкой при обновлении записи jsp - hibernate - mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, кодировка, spring-security

Всем привет!
Понимая, что тем обсуждающих те или иные проблемы с кодировкой масса, я перерыл многие, но увы решения не нашел, поэтому обращаюсь к вам, друзья!

Проблема собственно в том, что при попытке внести изменение в БД (jsp-hibernate-MySql) появляются кракозябры, вместо кириллицы.
Создавал базу так

```
`create database universityapp DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`
```

Фильтр в конфигурации развертывания приложения присутствует

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterEncoding = container.addFilter("characterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    filterEncoding.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    filterEncoding.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    filterEncoding.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "dispatcher");
```

Так же из проперти url базы прописан так

```
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Так же в server.xml в tomcat прописал кодировку

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8443" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Но ничего не помогает, ключевое тут то, что кодировка стала слетать, как только я добавил авторизацию в приложение с помощью Spring Security, до этого все работало правильно и записи в бд были кириллицой.

Конфигурационный класс Spring Security

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/students", "/subjects").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/student/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/AccessDenied");
    }
}
```

Инициализационный класс Spring Security

```
 import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{
}
```

Конфигурация Spring MVC

```
 @Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.kubar.universityapp") 
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{ 

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() { // Бин, определяющий файл с сообщениями
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) { 
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

Класс развертывания приложения

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer { 

public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class);


    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx)); 
    ctx.setServletContext(container);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
            "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterOpenSession = container.addFilter("openEntityManagerInViewFilter", OpenSessionInViewFilter.class);
    filterOpenSession.setInitParameter("singleSession", "true");
    filterOpenSession.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "dispatcher");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterEncoding = container.addFilter("characterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    filterEncoding.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    filterEncoding.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    filterEncoding.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "dispatcher");

}
```

}

И настройки Hibernate

```
    @Configuration 
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.kubar.universityapp.configuration" }) 
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"}) // Месторасположение properties файла
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.kubar.universityapp.model");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() { 
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired 
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Привет!
Мне помогло решение из этого [поста](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23051264).
Я не использую web.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ключевое тут действительно Spring Security. Твой filterEncoding должен стоять первым, а в случае с использование Security встаёт после FilterChain. 3 дня маялся, мне помог ответ из [этого поста](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051264).

Comment: Александр, спасибо вам за ответ! Он мне помог

Comment: Рад помочь! Сам промаялся 3 дня...